# Animating and updaing a Progress Ring

Tags: javascript, css, animation

Working on a visual Heath meter for my players, I got it working as 3 horizontal divs, and made one with circles but combining the two so the circles can be dynamically updated and have a animation/broken into bits/stripes has been a problem. i just can't figure out how to merge the methodologies.

EDIT: Notably my main problem is getting the SVG ring to have animated stripes like the Energy bar. as well as making the energy bar scroll up, think an Elevator. I can make it animate with a minor angle but I want it to be stright and to move upward

[image: result]

this is how far I got (javascript and css at the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nekollx/juczm0bh/)

```
class ProgressRing extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const stroke = this.getAttribute('stroke');
    const radius = this.getAttribute('radius');
    const normalizedRadius = radius - stroke * 2;
    this._circumference = normalizedRadius * 2 * Math.PI;

    this._root = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    this._root.innerHTML = `
      <svg
        height="${radius * 2}"
        width="${radius * 2}"
       >
         <circle
           stroke="green"
           stroke-dasharray="${this._circumference} ${this._circumference}"
           style="stroke-dashoffset:${this._circumference}"
           stroke-width="${stroke}"
           fill="transparent"
           r="${normalizedRadius}"
           cx="${radius}"
           cy="${radius}"
        />
      </svg>

      <style>
        circle {
          transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.35s;
          transform: rotate(-90deg);
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        }
      </style>
    `;
  }

  setProgress(percent) {
    const offset = this._circumference - (percent / 100 * this._circumference);
    const circle = this._root.querySelector('circle');
    circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['progress'];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (name === 'progress') {
      this.setProgress(newValue);
    }
  }
}

window.customElements.define('progress-ring', ProgressRing);

// emulate progress attribute change
let progress = 0;
const el = document.querySelector('progress-ring');

const interval = setInterval(() => {
  progress += 10;
  el.setAttribute('progress', progress);
  if (progress === 100)
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial) for that purpose.

In svg you can make progress ring via [circle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle), [dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset) and [dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray)

Thanks...